# Difficulty accessing actual objects in "didInsertElement" code in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm having a repeated problem with accessing elements, specifically elements obtained via reference from another element, in Ember. I have javascript running in a "didInsertElement" hook in the view, which is what most places on the web seem to indicate is the correct place to be running that logic.

However, the ember object I'm trying to access isn't real - Ember (presumably EmberData) is returning a blank placeholder object that doesn't have any of the required values. Every attribute is undefined.

I've tried waiting for the promise to resolve... but it's not a promise, it's just a fake object with undefined attributes. I've tried using Ember.run.next, to insure things finished loading first. Neither of these two solutions, or any of the others I've tried, have worked.

Here's an example of what I mean:
template:

```
{{#each entry in list.entries}}
  {{display-note note=entry}}
{{/each}}
```

component:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  alert(this.get("note").get("title"));
}
```

This inconsistently returns "undefined", even more inconsistently in situations where I'm passing a list of objects (something like `{{display-notes notes=list.entries}}` ).

Doing things like `{{list.entry.title}}` in the template works fine, though - the data is loading, it's just that it's being replaced by a "fake object" until that happens, and I don't know how to tell the ember app to wait until it's real to run my code and try and access it.

This is especially true for *self* references. Sometimes, rarely, the above code seems to work - but if I have a tree of, say, comments, which `hasMany` comments as `children`, attempting to access `children` fails even in the template. This might be due to another problem, though, or a combination of the two issues.

Comment: shouldn't it be {{#each entry in list}}?

Comment: I pluralized it to make it clearer. It's actually a relationship off list. Changed it to "list.entries". If this is still wrong, of course, let me know, because that would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `note` is undefined here:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  alert(note.get("title"));
}
```

With `didInsertElement`, start from the current view (i.e. `this`) and get your data from there. Assuming you are in the `NoteView` it would look like this:

```
App.NoteView = Ember.View.extend({
  title : 'hello world'

  didInsertElement: function (){
    alert(this.get('title'));
  }
})
```

Comment: No, note is defined there - it just has all of its attributes, aside from id, undefined. The id is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. >_< A typo, on my part. That was supposed to be this.get("note").